# 1960s short story, aliens accidentally set fire to the field they land in

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

I believe I read this work in the 70s. As I recall it was one of several short works in paperback, US printing.

They story has a dialog between some astronauts. They are discussing the possibilities of life on the planet they are going to. There are significant differences in temperature between their planet and the one they are going to.

Seems like there was something about the highly corrosive atmosphere of the destination planet (20% oxygen), they land in level area which turns out to be a grass field or meadow that catches on fire from the heat of their ship.

The idea of combustion/fire in the environment was incomprehensible to the astronauts, not sure if was do to lack of Oxygen on their home world, or because they lived under water.

Comment: It is not the same work asked about at [Short story about planet deemed uninhabitable due to poisonous oxygen clouds around it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59617)

Comment: I think you should add that to the question itself, as comments may be overlooked.

Comment: Was one of the landing party endangered by the fire and used a backfire to save himself/herself?

Comment: @KyleJones  I remember a member of the party being endangered. Now that you mention it, there may have been a back fire. Maybe caused accidentally, but the party got accolades for it later in the story

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Iceworld"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceworld) by Hal Clement, published 1953, is not a short story but a novel, but otherwise matches your description roughly. According to Wikipedia, the novel was originally serialized in the magazine Astounding in 1951, so your short story may have been one episode of this novel.

> They are discussing the possibilities of life on the planet they are going to.

The alien astronauts already know about humans, but speculate about an aggressive species in other regions, where their landers always are lost.

> There are significant differences in temperature between their planet and the one they are going to.

They come from an world hot enough for sulfur being a gas and taking the role that oxygen has in our world.

> Seems like there was something about the highly corrosive atmosphere of the destination planet (20% oxygen),

In "Iceworld", liquid water is the big problem, as it freezes the alien astronauts due to its high [enthalpy of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization#Other_common_substances).

> they land in level area which turns out to be a grass field or meadow that catches on fire from the heat of their ship.

The big fire happens when the lander accidentaly brushes some trees, leading to a wildfire. Two children are endangered by the fire, but saved by the alien astronaut.